# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Produk could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\oophp\produk.php on line 12

Tags: php

Please help to solve this error.
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Produk could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\oophp\produk.php on line 12

```
***
class  Produk {
public $judul = "judul";
public $penulis = "penulis";
public $penerbit = "penerbit";
public $harga = 0;

public function getLabel() {
    return "$this->$penulis, $this->$penerbit";
}
}

$produk3 = new Produk();
$produk3->judul = "Naruto";
$produk3->penulis = "Masashi Kishimoto";
$produk3->penerbit = "Shonen Jump";
$produk3->harga = 30000;
echo "Komik : " . $produk3->getLabel();
```

---

Comment: this error public function getLabel() {
    return "$this->$penulis, $this->$penerbit";
}

Comment: Read [this page of the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Answer (score -1):

You dont need the $ before the field you are trying to access

`"$this->$penulis, $this->$penerbit"`

Should be
`"$this->penulis, $this->penerbit"`